# Is it a problem to temporarily have the same UUID for two partitions?

Tags: 16.04, ssd, partitioning, uuid

While following the instructions in [Move your Linux installation to a new Solid State Drive - even a smaller one](http://blog.oaktreepeak.com/2012/03/move_your_linux_installation_t.html), I got stuck right after point "9." where I have copied the UUID of sdb6 (filesystem of the running ubuntu on HDD) on sda1 (wannabe new filesystem in the SSD) using tune2fs.

While I try to get un-stuck...(I'll post a thread soon about it) is it a problem to run the system while having the same UUID on two partitions?

If so, considering as well that I don't know the original UUID of the sda1 partition, would it be ok to just invent one, for example by changing a character of the UUID?

System information
Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
...
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 225282211 225280164 107.4G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
...
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048 318919887 318917840 152.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       318920702 976771071 657850370 313.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       960151552 976771071  16619520   7.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6       318920704 960151551 641230848 305.8G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Yes each partition should have a unique UUID and you update the system files (grub and fstab)

Comment: Yes, it might be a problem, because it's typical to use `UUID` for mounting partitions at boot in `/etc/fstab` file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some system tools refer to partitions by UUID numbers. This is common in `/etc/fstab`, for instance; partitions are identified for mounting by their UUID numbers rather than in some other way. Thus, duplicate UUID numbers can cause confusion and inconsistency -- on one boot, one partition might be mounted; but on another mount, the other partition might be mounted. This could create problems if files on that partition are changed, as is likely on most partitions.

You can learn what UUID a partition uses via the `blkid` command:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sdc3
/dev/sdc3: UUID="5028fa50-0079-4c40-b240-abfaf28693ea" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Xubuntu /boot" PARTUUID="74ed9e82-2e96-4a12-89e0-e0563c296a08"
```

This example reveals that `/dev/sdc3` has a UUID of 5028fa50-0079-4c40-b240-abfaf28693ea.

You can change a UUID with various filesystem-specific tools. For ext2/3/4fs, this tool is called `tune2fs`, and you pass it the `-U` option to change a UUID. You will, however, need a new UUID, and you can generate this with the `uuidgen` tool, which you can call as part of the call to `tune2fs`:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -U $(uuidgen) /dev/sdc3
```

You'd need to change the device ID (`/dev/sdc3` in this example) for your system, of course.

If your partition uses a filesystem other than ext2/3/4fs, you'll need to use a tool other than `tune2fs`, such as `xfs_admin` for XFS or `btrfstune` for Btrfs.

If the partition is being mounted in `/etc/fstab`, identified by UUID in a `grub.cfg` file, or otherwise referenced, you may need to adjust that configuration file after making your change.

Answer (score 2):

### If you need to change UUID for NTFS partitions it's a bit different:

There's actually a very good solution to this on this [Ubuntu Forum Thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1240146).

---

For NTFS partitions this is a complete list of steps I did (everything went well and no data was lost for me):

**Always keep a backup of your partition you are about to edit**

`blkid` to check existing uuids of your partition using, FYI, this is my output, note the UUID for later

```
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="EXT-HD-JS" 
TYPE="ntfs" 
UUID="983C4B493C4B221C" 
PARTUUID="0021f320-01"
```

`mount | grep "/dev/sdd1"` Make sure your partition is not mounted!

Now we install a hexeditor, copy the 512bytes superblock data into your user home, and edit the data:

```
sudo apt install ncurses-hexedit
sudo dd if=/dev/sdd1 of=~/superblock1 bs=512 count=1
sudo hexeditor ~/superblock1
```

Look at bytes 0x48 to 0x4f: `1C 22 4B 3C 49 4B 3C 98`

These are the bytes in reverse order as the UUID it displayed with blkid

Change start to `1D` (minimal change is always better)

Exit the hexeditor with Ctrl+X, type enter to save under same file.

Next we copy back the superblock data with the changed UUID, reboot and check the UUID again:

```
sudo dd if=~/superblock1 of=/dev/sdd1 bs=512 count=1
sudo reboot now
blkid
```